Clarification of $\sigma$-field generated by an optional time
In Karatzas& Shreve definition 2.20, given $T$ be an optional time of a filtration $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}_{t\in [0,+\infty)}$, $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}_{T+}$ is defined as

consisting of all event $A\in\mathcal{F}$ satisfying that $A\cap \{T\leq t\}\in \mathcal{F}_{t+}$  for all $t\geq 0$.

I am not 100% sure about the definition of $\mathcal{F}_{t+}$ when $t=\infty$. Here $\mathcal{F}_{t+}$ is defined as $\cap_{\varepsilon>0} \mathcal{F}_{t+\varepsilon}$ but we don't really define $\mathcal{F}_{\infty+\varepsilon}$.
I think the only interpretation is to define $\mathcal{F}_{\infty+}=\mathcal{F}_{\infty}$ and then $A\in\mathcal{F}_{T+}$ implies that $A\in \mathcal{F}_\infty$. Is there anything wrong with this?

It is not necessary to define $\mathcal F_{\infty+}$ but you could define it as $\mathcal F_{\infty}$ if you wish. In the definition you have, $t \ge 0$ is supposed to mean $0\le t <\infty$.

@geetha290krm I assume in Karatzas&Shreve they mean $t\in [0,+\infty]$ when they say $t\geq 0$. For example, they define $\mathcal{F}_T$ associated with stopping time $T$ as ${A\in\mathcal{F}|A\cap{T\leq t}\in \mathcal{F}_t,\forall t\geq 0}$. If we exclude $t=+\infty$ here, it seems that $A\in \mathcal{F}T$ doesn't necessarily imply that $A\in \mathcal{F}\infty$.  If this is true, then some nice things are gone. For example, the nice property $\mathcal{F}_T\subset \mathcal{F}_S$ if $T\leq S$ is gone, by taking $S=+\infty$.

I can assure you that KS do not mean $t\in[0,+\infty],.$ Besides: that nice thing is still true: When $S=+\infty$ then for all finite $t\ge 0$ the set ${S\le t}$ is empty
and we have trivially that for every $A\in{\cal F}$ the set $A\cap{S\le t}$ is in ${\cal F}_t,.$ This means that ${\cal F}_S={\cal F},.$ By definition:
${\cal F}_T\subset{\cal F}$ and so ${\cal F}_T\subset{\cal F}_S,.$

To be precise: KS assume $0\le t <+\infty$ in the definition of ${\cal F}T$ that you quoted. Nonetheless: they introduce ${\cal F}{+\infty+}$ through the backdoor as ${\cal F}{T+}$ when $T$ is an optional time (but again in that definition $t$ is finite as well!). As in my previous comment it is easy to see that ${\cal F}{+\infty+}$ can only be ${\cal F},.$

@KurtG. You are right about that example. However, nothing goes wrong if we assume $t\in [0,+\infty]$. The only difference is whether we have $\mathcal{F}T\subset \mathcal{F}\infty$. If we think $\mathcal{F}T$ as all info accumulated up to $T$, while $\mathcal{F}\infty$ as all info accumulated till infinity. It seems natural to have $\mathcal{F}T\subset \mathcal{F}\infty$. BTW, how can you be sure of what they mean? One of them is your professor, or you know that assume $t\in [0,+\infty]$ leads to some problem?

Have I not shown that we have $\mathcal{F}T\subset \mathcal{F}\infty$ without assuming $0\le t\color{red}\le\infty$ in the definition of ${\cal F}T,?$ Secondly, if you absolutely want to modify that definition please go ahead. Note that with that modification it necessarily implies ${\cal F}\subset{\cal F}\infty,,$ hence ${\cal F}={\cal F}_\infty,.$ For the life of me, I can't see that assumption being made anywhere in KS.

@KurtG. Where did you show $\mathcal{F}T\subset\mathcal{F}\infty$ without assuming $t\in [0,+\infty]$?

I showed that in my first comment.

@KurtG That I disagree. In general $F_\infty$ is defined as $\sigma(\cup_{t\in [0,+\infty)} F_t)$. That is why it is reasonable to think $F_\infty$ as all the info accumulated till $+\infty$. If we consider a filtration generated by a constant process, then $\mathcal{F}t$ is trivial for all $t\in [0,+\infty)$ and $\mathcal{F}\infty$ is trivial as well.

I view this as another drawback of excluding $t=+\infty$ from the definition. As now $F_\infty$ can be viewed either as what I just mentioned, or as $sigma$-algebra associated with a constant stopping time $+\infty$. In the later case it is $\mathcal{F}$. But then $\mathcal{F}_\infty$ may not be a proper model of all info till $+\infty$.

I will not continue this discussion unless you have more evidences showing that considering $t\in [0,+\infty]$ leads to a problem.

It is not my obligation to show that your phenomenal revolution will lead to a problem. Have a nice day.

There's no need to define $\mathcal F_{\infty+}$, at least when discussing $\mathcal F_{T+}$. But the comments highlight a problem with the definition used by K&S: Notice that $\mathcal F_\infty:=\sigma(\cup_{t\ge 0}\mathcal F_t)=\sigma(\cup_{t\ge 0}\mathcal F_{t+})$. Suppose $T$ is an optional time and $A\in\mathcal F_{T+}$. Then $A\cap\{T\le t\}\in \mathcal F_{t+}$ for all $t\ge 0$, so $A\cap\{T<\infty\}\in\mathcal F_\infty$. But what of $A\cap\{T=\infty\}$? Clearly $\{T=\infty\}\in \mathcal F_\infty$, and $A\in \mathcal F$ as a matter of definition.
As Kurt G. pointed out, if $S$ is identically $\infty$, then $S$ is an optional time and $\mathcal F_S=\mathcal F$. But a problem arises if the inclusion $\mathcal F_\infty\subset \mathcal F$ is strict, for then $\mathcal F_\infty\not= \mathcal F_S$, and the notation is incoherent.
Example Let $(X_t, Y_t)$ be a two-dimensional Brownian motion. Let $\mathcal F:=\sigma(X_t, Y_t: 0\le t<\infty)$ and let $(\mathcal F_t)$ be the filtration generated by $(X_t)$ alone. Then $\mathcal F_\infty=\sigma(X_t: 0\le t<\infty)$ is a proper subset of $\mathcal F$. Let $T$ be an $(\mathcal F_t)$ optional time such that $\{T=\infty\}$ is non-empty. Consider the event
$$
A:=\{T<\infty, X_T\ge b\}\cup\{T=\infty, Y_1\ge 0\},
$$
where $b$ is chosen so small that $\{T<\infty, X_T\ge b\}$ is non-empty. Clearly $A\in \mathcal F$. For each finite $t\ge 0$,
$$
A\cap\{T\le t\}=\{T\le t, X_T\ge b\}\in\mathcal F_{t+},
$$
so $A\in\mathcal F_{T+}$. But $A\cap\{T=\infty\}=\{T=\infty,Y_1\ge 0\}\in\mathcal F\setminus \mathcal F_\infty$. Therefore $\mathcal F_{T+}$ is not contained in $\mathcal F_\infty$.
It would be better to alter the definition of $\mathcal F_{T+}$, insisting that $A\in\mathcal F_\infty$.

So you suggest to define $\mathcal{F}_T$ associated with stopping time $T$ of filtration $(\mathcal{F}t)$ as ${A\in \mathcal{F}\infty|A\cap {T\leq t}\in \mathcal{F}t, \forall t\in [0,+\infty)}$, and similar for $\mathcal{F}{T+}$? I did some search and this agrees with the def in Revoz&Yor. This def makes whether to include $t=+\infty$ immaterial and also guarantee that $\mathcal{F}T\subset\mathcal{F}\infty$. The latter is all what I try to insist in the previous discussion.

Precisely what I had in mind.
